# Gnuplot: how to save variables in a table. Aiming to find the best fitting range.

Tags: gnuplot, cat

I have a set of data points x,y that are linear in certain range and gradually deviate from linearity in another certain range.

So I want to make a plot of "r" (linear regression factor) vs "x" . In that plot I could determine when r goes far from 1 and I could determine the best range for  linear fitting.
I want to do a plot like the following inset:

[Fig 2 of the following paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0614](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMmFX.png)

So my idea is like this so far:

```
reset
file1 = "file1.dat"
do for [ nxz=0:50] {
fitrangein=150+nxz
fitrangefin=300
stats [fitrangein:fitrangefin] file1  u 1:2
print STATS_correlation
}
```

The question is: how can I storage the values of STATS_correlation in a table? so, I could use later:

```
plot "r_values_vs_x_variable.dat" u 1:2
```

where col 1 must contain the x values and col 2 the values of STATS_correlation generated in every cycle of the "do for".

I suspect I need some kind of option of cat command, so first value of STATS_correlation can be pasted in line 1, second value in line 2 and so on.
But I cannot figure out how to do it exactly.

Do you have any suggestion or some different idea?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output of the `print` command by using `set print`, see `help set print`. Something like

```
set print "r_values_vs_x_variable.dat"
do for ... {
    ....
    print fitrangein, STATS_correlation
}
set print
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, just to know. Is the last  -- set print -- necessary?

Comment: The final `set print` restores the output channel for the subsequent `print` commands to STDERR. You definitely need it if you have later `print` commands that you don't want to output into that file. Even if you don't, it might be safer to have that statement in there because it might cause gnuplot to "close" the file (it depends on how the functionality is implemented, which I do not know), which could solve potential caching issues (especially if you want to read in that file within the same gnuplot script).

Answer (score 0):

Since version 5.0, gnuplot can also print to a named datablock, which can be used like a file but is not stored to disk:

```
set print $data 
do for [i=1:10] {print i, i**2}
set print
plot $data us 1:2
```

Has the advantage of not cluttering up your hard drive with temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to simply plot the difference quotient:

```
plot lx=NaN, ly=NaN, dataf us (llx=lx,lx=$1,lly=ly,ly=$2, (lx+llx)/2):((lly-ly)/(llx-lx))
```

The "using" specifier makes heavy use of the serial evaluation operator "," to shift the last data values through lx and llx, rsp. ly and lly.